# Можно ли выполнить функцию сохранив результат в динамической памяти

Tags: c++

У меня есть функция, возвращающая объект на стеке. Мне же нужно результат сохранить в динамической памяти. Можно ли это сделать без копирования? Функцию изменить нельзя, объект очень большой, *move*-семантика не предусмотрена библиотекой. Пробовал побайтово скопировать объект, но использовать его после выхода из функции нельзя т.к. деструктор разрушает необходимые для работы с объектом данные.

Comment: Ну так аллоцируйте в функции возвращаемый объект сразу в куче. Если функцию менять нельзя, выхода нет.

Comment: А что значит «использовать его после выхода из функции нельзя т.к. деструктор разрушает неоодимые для работы с объектом данные»? То есть вам функция возвращает мёртвый объект? Ну так эту функцию тогда в любом случае нельзя использовать.

Comment: Скорее всего выхода нет. Возвращаемый объект работает до вызова деструктора как и полагается. Я наивно пытался скопировать полученый объект побайтово, но понятное дело что после вызова деструктора он разрушает выделенные в куче подобъекты и получается мертвая копия.

Comment: Вы приведите упрощенный пример, а то что-то очень невнятно получается у вас пояснить, что есть и что нужно. Ощущение, что этот объект функция у вас НЕ возвращает...

Comment: Приведите имеющийся код, раз уж он у Вас есть. А то даже сигнатура функции не ясна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, в C++ есть RVO - оптимизация возвращаемого значения, когда объект вроде как создается на стеке (судя по коду программы), но по факту, копирования при возврате не происходит:

```
std::string test()
{
    std::string ret="qqq";
    //...
    return ret;
}
```

Если вас такое не устраивает, используйте new() и создавайте объект на куче.

При особом желании таки выделить объект на стеке, можно память взять из стека вызывающей функции при помощи alloca(), а затем разместить в ней объект, используя placement-new().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        cout << "construct" << endl;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        cout << "destruct" << endl;
    }
};

Foo* user(void* mem)
{
    cout << " create" << endl;
    return new(mem) Foo();
}

int main() 
{

    void* mem=alloca(sizeof(Foo));
    assert(mem);
    Foo* foo=user(mem);
    cerr << "delete" << endl;
    foo->~Foo(); // нужно ЯВНО вызвать деструктор
    //а вот память, выделенную alloca, освобождать НЕ НУЖНО.
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/7uZjnd)

Comment: Не понятно, а почему изначально не выделить динамически память вместо использования нестандартной функции?

Comment: Выделение динамической памяти стоит дорого - можно ненароком и контекст переключить. Данный не совсем чистый, с точки зрения стандарта трюк, позволяет усидеть на двух стульях - создать объект на стеке, не тратя времени на поход за памятью в кучу, и не совершать дополнительного копирования с деструкцией. И даже не совершать перемещения (!). Приличные компиляторы в этом месте делают RVO, я показываю, как сотворить RVO путем грубой силы.